# ANGULAR 2 - Component Shared Data Service

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

this has really been wreaking my head.

I have a nice little app with social login setup using Firebase and Angular 2.

Everything should be realtime. Basically when a user logs in via Facebook I want their personal info to be passed to a service and stored as an Observable and display instantly in any component that subscribes to the service, I then want to be able to access this Observable from within Components that are not directly linked to each other and may even be totally out of the hierarchy.. hence why I cant use @Input or an EventEmitter etc..

I have tried a lot of different things but at its most stripped back this is what i currently have, a login component that passes the users data to the service and then a random component that should be able to access this data in realtime as soon as it hits the service.

*** my login component ***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GlobaluserService } from '../globaluser.service';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent  {

  email: string;
  password: string;
  userData = {};
  _api;

  constructor( public af: AngularFire,  private router: Router, private api: GlobaluserService ) {
    this._api = this.api;
  }

  loginFacebook() {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup,
    }).then( ( facebookUser ) => {

        this.userData = {
          uID: facebookUser.auth.uid,
          profilePic: facebookUser.auth.photoURL,
          username: facebookUser.auth.displayName,
          email: facebookUser.auth.email,
          platform: 'facebook'
        }

        this._socialLoginProcess( this.userData );  // this method is described below

    }).catch( (error) => {
      console.log("Facebook failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }

  // passes the user data to the shared service and outputs the data in the console
  _socialLoginProcess( userData ) {
    this._api.saveData(userData); 
    console.log("Login Success: " + JSON.stringify( this.userData )); 
  }


}
```

*** Shared Service ***

```
import { Component, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


// Name Service
export interface usersData {
    uID: string,
    profilePic: string,
    username: string,
    email: string,
    platform: string
}


@Injectable()
export class GlobaluserService {

  sharingData: Observable<usersData[]>

  private _sharingData: BehaviorSubject<usersData[]>;

  private dataStore: {
    sharingData: usersData[]
  };


  constructor() {
    this.dataStore = { sharingData: [] };
    this._sharingData = <BehaviorSubject<usersData[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
  }

  saveData( userData ) {
    this.sharingData = userData; 
  }

  getData()  {
    console.log('get data function called' +  JSON.stringify( this.sharingData ) );
    return this._sharingData.asObservable();
  }


}
```

*** Random Component I wish to be able to get the users data from this service ***

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GlobaluserService } from '../globaluser.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-navigation',
templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})

export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit  {

  isAuth = false;
  user   = {};

  subscription   : any;
  userKonte      : any;
  _userAPIservice: any;

  constructor( private router: Router, private api: GlobaluserService ) {

      this.subscription    = this.api.getData().subscribe( _sharingData => {
          this.userKonte = _sharingData;
          console.log( JSON.stringify( this.userKonte )  );
      });

  }

    ngOnInit(){
      console.log( JSON.stringify( this.userKonte )  );
    }





}
```

Comment: What wrong with this? Are you getting errors, wrong results? If so please explain.

Comment: Its not returning anything at all, its not giving an error but its just not giving me any data... in the service I get the console output of the data I want but in the component in the subscribe nothing is being returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
saveData( userData ) {
  this.sharingData = userData; 
}
```

when you want to emit a new value, you need to `next` on the `BehaviorSubject`

```
saveData( userData ) {
  this._sharingData.next(userData); 
}
```

Because `getData` is getting the observable from the subject, the subscribers to the observable will get the new emissions on the subject when `next` is called

Comment: Oh man.... I could kiss you.. so bloody simple. Could I be so bold as to ask what does this do exactly

Comment: Subject is both a publisher and subscriber. The subscriber part is the observable you get from asObservable. When you want to publish to it, you need to call `next`, and all subscribers get it.

Comment: oh yeah and while I have you there i just want to make sure is the way I am doing this 100% correct, i.e the way my service is setup etc.. for a production app ?

Comment: It looks fine, though you might as well remove the `signingData` observable, since you're using `getData`

Comment: haha sorry man while ive got you there. When I refresh the browser it doesnt keep the data, the user still stays logged in but I guess thats because of how firebase works but the data service doesnt remember anything.. you wouldnt know what i should be looking into next to keep a persistant service would you

Comment: I thought that but I wasnt sure how that would work.. it kind of makes the service redundant then as I should just save everything into localstorage which also seems like overkill