# passing one component data to other component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-components

I am getting response from server,I want pass this response to other component for displaying. I tried in one way but getting undefined. 
Tried this way [how to pass one component service response to other component in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092315/how-to-pass-one-component-service-response-to-other-component-in-angular-2).
yesterday got the results faced routing. Changed little bit created separated components.

mainsearch.component.ts:

```
export class MainsearchComponent {

  selected;
  skipCount: number = 0;
  errorMessage: string;
  searchedResults: any;

  searchObj: Object = {

    skipCount: this.skipCount

  };

  onChange(newVlaue) {
    console.log(newVlaue);

    this.selected = newVlaue;
  }

  constructor(private searchService: searchService, private router: Router) { }

  searchall() {

    console.log(this.searchObj);

    var searchData = this.searchObj;
    console.log(searchData);

    this.searchService.getSearchbyDistrictCategoryCity(this.searchObj).subscribe(
     data => {
      this.searchedResults = data;
      this.searchService.searchResults = data;
      console.log(this.searchedResults);
      console.log(this.searchService.searchResults);
      this.router.navigate(['/searchdetails']);
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
}
```

searchdetails.component.ts:

```
export class SearchdetailsComponent {

  searchedResults:any;

  constructor(private searchService: searchService) {
    this.searchedResults = this.searchService.searchResults;
    console.log(this.searchedResults);  
  }
}
```

search.service.ts:

```
export class searchService {

  public searchResults;

  private searchAllUrl: string = "http://192.168.1.134:8000/app/school/searchbydistrictandcategoryandlocation"

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getSearchbyDistrictCategoryCity(searchObj) {
    // console.log(searchObj);
    // let body = JSON.stringify({ searchObj });
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post(this.searchAllUrl, searchObj, { headers: headers })
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {

    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

now routing working fine,
but data is not getting in searchdetails component

Comment: try EventEmitter for pass data from one component to another component.

Comment: @Chandru can you elaborate and i am new angular 2/4

Comment: In your `SearchdetailsComponent` component, set `this.searchedResults` in  `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `constructor`

Comment: @Faisal Thanks .Can you elaborate

Comment: Add service provider in root component i.e., app component and remove providers from searchdetails.component.ts and mainsearch.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can define a factory service (shared data service) and have a array of objects there then fill array from your response and use this array in other component by including the service tag on component.

you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40900531/angular-2-component-shared-data-service)

Comment: Passing the object from component to service as object and getting results and the results.I want to pass and display this results to other component when routing does

Comment: Add service provider in root component i.e., app component and remove providers from searchdetails.component.ts and mainsearch.component.ts

Comment: Actually I just introduced the concept that what we used in AngularJs 1.2, I haven't go through with AngularJs 2 practically.

Answer (score 0):

This is a asynchrounous function:

```
getSearchbyDistrictCategoryCity(searchObj) {
// console.log(searchObj);
// let body = JSON.stringify({ searchObj });
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.http.post(this.searchAllUrl, searchObj, { headers: headers })
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here you are assigning the result in the constructor:

```
export class SearchdetailsComponent {

  searchedResults:any;

  constructor(private searchService: searchService) {
    this.searchedResults = this.searchService.searchResults;
    console.log(this.searchedResults);  
  }
}
```

At the moment you are assigning the `searchService.searchResults` to the search results in your `SearchdetailsComponent` the function in your search service may not be complete.

You could access the `searchService.searchResults` from the template of your search details component because it's public.
A better way would be to subscribe to the search function from your service in your search details too.